# ClassCastException for com.querydsl.core.Tuple

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am getting exception as

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.chat.dao.model.PGUserRoles cannot be cast to com.querydsl.core.Tuple
```

My code seems to be correct.

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager);
QPGUserRoles pgUserRoles = QPGUserRoles.pGUserRoles;
List<Tuple> dataList = query
    .from(pgUserRoles)
    .where(isRoleName(userRolesDTO.getRoleName()),
        isRoleType(userRolesDTO.getRoleType()),
        isStatus(userRolesDTO.getStatus()),
        isStatusNotEq()
    )
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(limit)
    .orderBy(orderByRoleIdDesc())
    .fetch();
UserRolesDTO userData = null;
for (Tuple tuple : dataList) {
    userData = new UserRolesDTO();
    userData.setRoleId(tuple.get(pgUserRoles.roleId));
    userData.setRoleName(tuple.get(pgUserRoles.roleName));
    userData.setRoleType(tuple.get(pgUserRoles.roleType));
    userData.setStatus(tuple.get(pgUserRoles.status));
    userRoleList.add(userData);
}
```

Exception is thrown at line with `for`

I don't understand why exception is been throw. Tuple is generic query result projection. And the example in there [doc](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/Tuple.html) is similar to mine.
I'm using querydsl 4.2.1 version.

Comment: I think the `fetch` method is returning a `List<PGUserRoles>` rather than a `List<Tuple>`

Comment: It looks like the List returned by `List<Tuple> dataList = query` does not return a list of Tuples but rather PGUserRoles. Beware that although you use the Type Tuple in the list, the actual list may be of a different type. See [Type Erasue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke that's useless. It's like saying "I think there's an error" when  user literally said it in his post

Comment: @Jeroen Steenbeeke, you are right. It is returning List<PGUserRoles>. This code used to work correctly in mysema.querydsl v3 but after upgrading 
 to querydsl v4, things have messed up.

Comment: @Sarief pointing out an issue that normally only generates a warning at compile time but causes invalid casts at runtime is useless? The reason I added "I think" is because I do not know the specific API the question mentions, and the OP did not mention the generic type difference in his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after modifying my code a little bit wrt v4. Its working now. Thank you all for your support.

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(entityManager);
        QPGUserRoles pgUserRoles = QPGUserRoles.pGUserRoles;
        List<Tuple> dataList = query
                .from(pgUserRoles)
                .select(pgUserRoles.roleId,
                        pgUserRoles.roleName,
                        pgUserRoles.roleType,
                        pgUserRoles.status)
                .where(isRoleName(userRolesDTO.getRoleName()),
                        isRoleType(userRolesDTO.getRoleType()),
               isStatus(userRolesDTO.getStatus()),
               isStatusNotEq()
                )
                .offset(offset)
                .limit(limit)
                .orderBy(orderByRoleIdDesc())
                .fetch();
```

Answer (score -1):

query from generated class QPGUserRoles will return list of PGUserRoles, i.e. List

I have no idea what Tuple is, but it is allowed, apparently, because method return List but does not take actual parameter for list from the returned parameter but from supplied generated class. May be bad design or java limitation.

In all cases, you have to change your code. Your code is not correct, simply because it compiles :)

upd: Tuple is projection of Select statement. You don't use it - result is different ;)

Comment: This code used to work correctly in mysema.querydsl v3 but after upgrading to querydsl v4, things have messed up

Comment: In that case, revert back and figure out where the problem is. This looks to me like a bug, but might be a change in interface. Regardless, the only thing i can say: try debugging AND reading patch notes. If it's an introduced bug = make a report

Comment: @RC2793 if you do make a report, post a link as accepted answer here. You do need to debug in that case.